# Is their a straightforward way to limit the number of updates of a certain field in a django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

For example i use the extended user model called "profile" and in the profile i have many fields describing the using. what i want is that the user choose whether he is a business user or a regular customer on the web site. but once this field is updated it cannot be updated again, in which the field appears in the profile edit form but as non-editable field.

**What is the best way to do that?**

I thought of using an additional field in the database where i include an "update date" and if this field is not null then the user cannot update. but it seems to me too much coding for this small feature.

Thanks in advance

The code  :
forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['phone','profile_type','city','image']
```

template (html)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{userform.as_p}} <br>
                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>  {{profileform.profile_type.label}}</td>
                                <td>{{profileform.profile_type}}</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>  {{profileform.image.label}}</td>
                                <td>{{profileform.image}}</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>


                            <br>
                        <input type="submit" name="" value="Update Profile">



                        </form>
```

Views.py

```
def profile_edit(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        userform = UserForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        profileform = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=profile)
        if userform.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid():
            userform.save()
            myprofile = profileform.save(commit=False)
            
            myprofile.user = request.user
            
            myprofile.save()
            
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))

    else :
        
        userform = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profileform = ProfileForm(instance=profile)

    return render(request,'accounts/profile_edit.html',{'userform':userform , 'profileform':profileform})
```

Comment: Does the field for business user or regular user have a default value?

Comment: @Vincent Actually i extend the user model from django to add a profile. in the profile model i have a field called (user_type) with choices that i pass in a tuple in the models.py (Job Seeker) and (Company / Business). based on the choice of the user the website will be able to differentiate which tables to render. Now i plan to enforce the user upon the first login to choose a value (either job seeker or business) and once updated it cannot be updated once again. the default value is Null upon creation via signal – kiwis 31 mins ago   Delete

Comment: As you've not provided any code of how it's currently working, I think you can just check if the user_type field has a value and if not, set the value either to business user or regular user. If it has a value, don't update the field.

Comment: @Vincent I just added the code. 
The thing is that i have no idea how to disable a particular field based on an if statement as you can see the form is rendered as {{form}} in the template

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=(("a","a"), ("b","b")))

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._original_user_type = self.user_type
    
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self._original_user_type != self.user_type:
      raise ValidationError("You can't change user_type!")
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This should prevent you from changing `user_type` without requiring another field.

*(But I haven't tested it.)*

---

**updated**

In light of your updates it seems like you'd like to catch the error during form processing as opposed to model processing.  There are a number of ways to solve this.

You could add a custom `clean` method to the form to check if `user_type` has changed and raise a `ValidationError` if it has.  Something like:

```
def clean(self):
  cleaned_data = super().clean()
  instance = getattr(self, "instance", None)
  if instance and instance.pk and instance.user_type != cleaned_data["user_type"]:
    raise ValidationError("You can't change user_type!")
  return cleaned_data
```

You could add a custom `clean` method to the *field* to negate any changes to `user_type`.  Something like:

```
def clean_user_type(self):
  instance = getattr(self, "instance", None)
  if instance and instance.pk:
    return instance.user_type
  else:
    return self.cleaned_data["user_type"]
```

Or, you could just disable the `user_type` field if the underlying model already exists:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  instance = getattr(self, "instance", None)
  if instance and instance.pk:
    self.fields["user_type"].disabled = True
```

*(This is still untested code.)*

Comment: Thank you, but this does not really seem to be clear to me, i just added my code to the original post. i do not know how could this fit into it?